# Hidden and vertically align not working tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css

Here my code tailwind code(https://play.tailwindcss.com/BpsTxRawqf) .I tried using invisible property it works fine, but it takes up space in layout so I thought of switching over to hidden property. But it doesnt work. It keeps element hidden all the time.

Also vertically align is not working for it. I tried debugging but couldnt make it work. KIndly help me in this. a bit new to tailwind. thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="hidden divide-x divide-slate-400 font-semibold md:max-2xl:flex">
```

Set the default to `hidden` then chang `md:max-2xl:` to `flex`

Comment: Hi it works, can you please share why did we do that. adding flex instead of visibility. what difference does it make

Comment: `flex` means: `display: flex` which is the opposite of `hidden` => `display: hidden`. 
But `visible`: means: `visibility: visible` the opposite of `invisible` => `visibility: invisible`.